# Make message in syslog message if a program is opened

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I have a file containing program names.
If a program is opened, a syslog message should be generated.

So far, I have written a script to collect the id of each program; how should I generate the syslog message? Here's the script:

```
#!/bin/bash
filename=$1
while read line; do
s=$line
b=`pgrep $s`
if pgrep $s
then
echo "id of $s is $b"
else 
echo "$s  program isnt opened"
fi
done < $filename
```

Comment: Suggest you read https://askubuntu.com/editing-help#code to learn how formatting questions work. Also, if someone asks you for more information, please click [edit] and add it to your question, instead of using Add Comment.

Answer (score 1):

On my phone now but you can use the `logger` command:

```
logger "message to display including $variables`
```